# mysql update json attribute and another column in one query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-json

I need to update a json value in a column as well as update another column in the same query.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE fixtures 
SET jsonResults = '{}', 
    JSON_SET(jsonFixture, '$.time_status', '0') 
WHERE intRefID = 88961323;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON_SET()` returns a JSON document value, but an UPDATE statement needs a series of assignment expressions:

```
UPDATE fixtures 
SET jsonResults = '{}', 
    jsonFixture = JSON_SET(jsonFixture, '$.time_status', '0') 
WHERE intRefID = 88961323;
```

This replaces `jsonFixture` with the result of `JSON_SET()`, after setting a field within that document.

Compare with an UPDATE like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET i = i + 1
WHERE ...
```

It takes the value of `i`, adds 1, and then uses the result of that addition expression to replace `i`.